# Is there a equivalent application to Everything search engine (Windows) on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, search

IMO, [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) is the best desktop search software on Windows and I wonder if there is an equivalent utility on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Synapse, Gnome Do, the built in Nautilus search?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/714091/my-quest-to-find-the-fastest-search-app-for-linux

Answer (score 10):

You can try [tracker-search](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tracker-search) [image: Install tracker-search]

It is available in the Software Center.

To install it, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tracker-gui
```

After installing it, search for *Desktop Search* in the dash and open it. You can then search for the files and folders in the search bar.

[image]

Comment: I'm just tasting UBUNTU. `tracker-gui` is a very nice search app. I'm very surprised from searching within documents alongside files and folders! A great advantage.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be available on 17.10

Comment: 'Could not find tracker-search'

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 I get "E: Package 'tracker-gui' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 8):

An app called [FSearch](https://cboxdoerfer.github.io/fsearch/) could help with this.

> FSearch is a fast file search utility for GNU/Linux operating systems,
> inspired by Everything Search Engine. It's written in C and based on
> GTK+3.

It has regex support and instant results.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-daily
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install fsearch
```

[image]

Comment: Please change  "sudo apt install fsearch-trunk" to "sudo apt install fsearch"

Answer (score 7):

Install `synapse` from the software center or via the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Synapse is a semantic launcher written in Vala that you can use to start applications as well as find and access relevant documents and files by making use of the Zeitgeist engine.

It will index all your files - images, music, video, documents, applications, folders you visit, etc and you can launch them from there.

To activate just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> keys and just type your search terms. Scroll the results using the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> keys and browse the different categories using the <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd>. Once you find your result, press <kbd>enter</kbd> to launch.

See screenshot below after I typed 'ubu':

[image]

Comment: Hi, there is also <kbd>Tab</kbd> for selection alternate actions for a result.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 11.10 **Unity** presents this search function as the 1st option on the menu. Easy acess, very nice. Find applications, files, everything very fast. I recommend. =D

Comment: not even remotely as fast as `Everything` though.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus is capable of searching your whole computer. If you have external drivers, mount them and it will search on them too!

For instance, I have a drive called FILES, so I mount it and search a file from the root Ubuntu directory `/` and it is found and displayed in a list style:

[image: screenshoot]

To search for files in Nautilus press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then type the filename on the bar.

Comment: Yeah but i want a [list all files] program, for Dee duplication and sorting of my horribly disorganized 10 tb drives.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [FSearch](https://cboxdoerfer.github.io/fsearch/) is an Ubuntu equivalent of `Everythings` in Windows.

FSearch also could search Windows files (`fat32`, `NTFS` formats).

---

### Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install fsearch-trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Catfish. Not a perfect alternative but it claims to have an extension that allows querying and maintaining indexes.

Answer (score 0):

A different answer.

You can use wine + everything with some configrations.

1. tool -> option

   [image]
2. set the root directionary.

   [image]

Then, enjoy everything on ubuntu. :-P

[image]