# Is there any "Everything Search" like searching software in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-sources

I read the [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103755/is-there-a-equivalent-sofware-to-everything-search-engine-windows-on-ubuntu), but after installing "Desktop Search" I found that it is not working well, e.g. it can't find the files and folders which don't lie on the main drive. And also I've noticed that in the [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103755/is-there-a-equivalent-sofware-to-everything-search-engine-windows-on-ubuntu) the given solutions are not Accepted. I really want an accepted solution!!! :D
Could you tell me which searching software is the best on Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Best searching software is a command line app called `find`. It's very very versatile, and can be used to do a lot of funky stuff, from just listing files with specific attributes, to actually operating on those files . . . I don't think there is a GUI front-end to this command, but if you'd like , I could put together a script that will have a GUI. Are there any specific needs that you'd need this script to perform ?

Comment: Ah, somebody already did that . . . .[It's called Catfish](http://www.unixmen.com/catfish-graphical-front-end-find-locate-commands/)

Comment: @Serg - Nothing for special purpose, only to locate desired files and folders.

Comment: @Serg - Catfish is not bad, but I need more faster searching software!!!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/714091/my-quest-to-find-the-fastest-search-app-for-linux

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one such app now. [FSearch](https://cboxdoerfer.github.io/fsearch/).

It is still in beta, but has a lot of features that is similar to everything search under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check Gnome tool to search, it's a lightweight search tool

[Gnome Tool to Search](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gnome-search-tool/)